# Subquery having issues

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having one issue with sub query. I have to pass multiple ids to my sub query..but with my query i am not getting correct result...

Here is the My sample data and my table structure..

```
Employee Table:
------------------------
EMPLOYEE_ID NOT NULL    NUMBER(16)
EXTERNAL_ID_1       VARCHAR2(200)
EXTERNAL_ID_2       VARCHAR2(200)
JOB_PROFILE_TYPE        VARCHAR2(4)
FIRST_NAME  NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(200)
MIDDLE_NAME     VARCHAR2(200)

Alignment Table :
-------------------------
ALIGNMENT_ID    NOT NULL    NUMBER(16)
TEAM_ID NOT NULL    NUMBER(16)
EMPLOYEE_ID     NUMBER(16)
ALIGNMENT_NAME  NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(200)
EXTERNAL_ID_1       VARCHAR2(200)
STATUS  NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(4)
STATUS_CHANGE_DATE  NOT NULL    DATE
MANAGER_ALIGNMENT_ID        NUMBER(16)

Event table :
-------------------
EVENT_ID    NOT NULL    NUMBER(16)
EMPLOYEE_ID NOT NULL    NUMBER(16)
AFFILIATION_ID      NUMBER(16)
CUSTOMER_ID     NUMBER(16)
EXTERNAL_ID_1       VARCHAR2(200)

Sample data :
ALIGNMENT_ID    ALIGNMENT_NAME  EMPLOYEE_ID ROLE    MANAGER_ALIGNMENT_ID
1006034672  SII-KRN-BANG-A01    17452000001661  REP 1006034513
1006034673  SII-KRN-BANG-A02    18910000219453  REP 1006034513
1006034674  SII-KRN-BANG-A03    60000001963804  REP 1006034513
1006034675  SII-KRN-BANG-A05    60000001963706  REP 1006034514
1006034676  SII-KRN-BANG-A06    18910000081856  REP 1006034514
1006034677  SII-KRN-BANG-B01    60000001963699  REP 1006034513
```

My Query :

```
SELECT  *
FROM    event ev
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.employee_id=ev.employee_id
INNER JOIN alignment a ON e.employee_id=a.employee_id AND alignment_id in(:alignment_id)
```

Description :

I have the data stored in alignment table  with child records and parent records. In alignment table I have the data `alignment_id` and manager `alignment_id`.
For each rep there should one manager.(`manager_alignment_id`).
I have to integrate this query to front end..

In front end I have drop down values and will select multiple ids to pass to this query...
if the selection for `alignment_id(rep)` then no problem. If they will select `manager_alignment_id` then how to pass this value to mu query.

I am using oracle 11g version.

Comment: Please supply your tables' DDLs, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get so we can more easily help you.

Comment: Can you show your tables structure?

Comment: Why are you querying two times from alignment table? You can directly query employee id at the first place.

Comment: Normally the manager-subordinate relationship is modelled along the lines of `subordinate.manager_id = manager.employee_id`.  It looks like your model does something different.  So please explain how a manager and subordinates are actually joined.  Also, is this truly hierarchical?  Can a subordinate have their own staff, who can have their own staff, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN alignment A ON A.employee_id = E.employee_id
                         AND (A.manager_alignment_id = <Your value here>
                            OR A.alignment_id = <Your value here>)
```

This query returns every rows corresponding to the defined `manager_alignment_id` or `alignment_id`.

Hope this will help you.